# StackOverflow Exception at runtime

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio

I am getting an exception when running this code.

```
public void insertRBT(int value)
        {
            //BNode newNode = new BNode(value);
            root=insertNode(root, value,null);
            count += 1;
        }

        protected BNode insertNode(BNode rt, int value, BNode parent)
        {
            BNode grandParent, greatGrandParent;
            if (rt == null)
            {

                BNode newNode = new BNode(value, parent);
                parent = newNode.parent;
                if (parent != null)
                {
                    if (value > parent.value)
                    {
                        parent.right = newNode;
                    }
                    else {
                        parent.left = newNode;
                    }
                }
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    newNode.red = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    newNode.red = false;
                }
                //added

                insertedNode = newNode;
                grandParent = null;
                greatGrandParent = null;
                insertFix(newNode,parent,grandParent,greatGrandParent);
                return newNode;
            }
            else if (value.CompareTo(rt.value) < 0)
            {
                rt.left = insertNode(rt.left, value, rt);
                return rt;
            }else //if(value.CompareTo(rt.value)> 0)
            {
                rt.right = insertNode(rt.right, value, rt);
                return rt;
            }
}
```

the error started occuring when I added the following code:

```
if (parent != null)
{
    if (value > parent.value)
    {
        parent.right = newNode;
    }
    else {
       parent.left = newNode;
     }
}
```

//BNode class

```
class BNode
    {
        public int value;
        public BNode left;
        public BNode right;
        public BNode parent; //check
        public Boolean red = true; // red=false - indicates black

        public BNode(int num, BNode parent)
        {
            value = num;
            left = null;
            right = null;
            this.parent = parent;
        }
}
```

Upon testing the code, I added 50, 75, 40, 45, 25 - and when I entered 25 the exception occurred.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace

Comment: asking about homework?

Comment: @MattBucci, that question is categorically irrelevant.

Comment: RedBlackTree.exe!RedBlackTree.RedBlackTree.insertNode(RedBlackTree.BNode rt, int value, RedBlackTree.BNode parent) Line 157 C#
  RedBlackTree.exe!RedBlackTree.RedBlackTree.insertNode(RedBlackTree.BNode rt, int value, RedBlackTree.BNode parent) Line 153 C#
  RedBlackTree.exe!RedBlackTree.RedBlackTree.insertNode(RedBlackTree.BNode rt, int value, RedBlackTree.BNode parent) Line 157 C#
  
The above is the stack trace and consists of a list of the lines alternating. the lines refer to where the value is compared to the root value

Comment: It seems you are in a loop, that's the reason why stack gets full. You maybe are inserting a new child node recursively in an infinite loop.

Comment: thought so however, what I can't understand is that this started occuring when I added the 5 lines of code I posted above which shouldn't be affecting the loop